# How to change an angular2 html dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

Im trying to find a way to change some html lines of a component dynamically.

```
<li *ngFor="p in persons" [attr.id]="p.id">
   <span> {{ p.name }} </span>                      
   <a (click)="getAge(p.id)">Get Age<a/>     
</li>
```

If the user clicks on the `Get Age` link i would like to replace the content inside of the corresponding `li` tag to something like:

```
<span> {{ p.OtherProperty }} </span> 
<a (click)="OtherMethod(p)">Call OtherMethod<a/>
```

I found that `ComponentFactoryResolver` to create dynamic components, but i found it too overwhelming for just 2 lines of html. And i tried to change it by hand using jquery but it does not work to create the event bindings:

```
getAge(id) { 
    //some work
    //remove the corresponding <li> content
    $('#' + id).append('<a (click)="getAnotherValue(p.name)">GetAnotherValue<a/>');
    $('#' + id).append('<span> {{ p.age}} </span>'); //this obviously doesnt work. But thats the ideia.
 }
```

So how can i replace some html tags with angular attributes dynamically?

Comment: Please use [tag:angularjs] tag for version 1.x only (Already retagged this  question). Thanks

Comment: it is a better practice in angular to avoid DOM manipulations like this, there are ng directives for dynamic html. A angular way to do this is to bind the html code to a controller variable, and the function click will modify the content of the variable. The changes should reflect automatically

Answer (score 1):

You could access the person's `Object` property dynamically like this:

```
object[property]; // Where property is a string
// If property equals 'name', the above sentence would equal this:
object.name; // or `object['name'];`
```

So, following your example, you could do this:

```
export class App {
  persons = [
    {
     id: 1,
     name: 'John',
     age: 25
    },
    {
     id: 2,
     name: 'Mike',
     age: 30
    }
  ];
  selectedProperty = 'name';

  constructor() {
  }

  getProperty(prop) {
    this.selectedProperty = prop;
  }
}
```

And in your template you could:

```
<div>
  <li *ngFor="let p of persons" [attr.id]="p.id">
    <span> {{ p[selectedProperty] }} </span>
    <br>
  </li>
  <button (click)="getProperty('age')">Get Age</button> 
  <button (click)="getProperty('name')">Get Name</button>
</div>
```

If I understood well, this should do the trick. You can't use `ngIf` because if you have 60 properties or persons then will be somewhat caothic.

[Check the Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/L1lytLBQ6yUpRLOAElxy?p=preview)

Comment: Good workaround. This works well for the person property, but im not sure if can resolve the button replacement.

Comment: You could replace the button with a `<select>` where each `<option>` is a property of the `person` object, such as: Age, Name, Surname, etc. And, `onChange()` of the select, you trigger `getProperty()` passing as parameter the value of the `<option>`.

Comment: That way you'll have many `<li>` elements *(one for each `person` in your `persons` object)* and a simple dropdown *(`<select>`)*.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ngIf` to activate the code as shown:

```
     <li *ngFor="p in persons" [attr.id]="p.id">

        <div *ngIf=!p?.touched>

             <span> {{ p.name }} </span>
             <a (click)="getAge(p)">Get Age<a/>
        </div>

        <div *ngIf=p?.touched>
            <span> {{ p.age}} </span> 
            <a (click)="getAnotherValue(p.name)">GetAnotherValue<a/>
       </div>  

     </li>

    isGetAgeClicked=false;

        getAge(person) { 
            //some work
            //remove the corresponding <li> content
         person.touched=true
         }
```

Comment: but if i have 10 <li> itens rendered. All of them will change if i clicked in one of them?

Comment: @gog Try the edited answer, I hope it will work for your case